# How to increment the value of request.getParameter?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to make an quiz and my query is ORDER BY RAND() so it means it will be random... My JSP send it to servlet to handle the flow but I'm having a problem, I have stored 4 questions with choices (answer) in the database and in my code below I retreive it. Problem is, when I retrieve the answer of the examinee the only retrieved data is the first answer... See my servlet

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>  
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>  
<%@page import="database.Connect" %>  

<%   
    Connect conn = new Connect();   
    Statement stmt = conn.getDataConn().createStatement();  
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from quiz WHERE category = 'secondary' ORDER BY RAND()");  

%>  

<html>  
    <head>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css&js/des.css">  
        <script src="css&js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>  

        <title>Question 1</title>  
    </head>  

    <body>  

        <img alt="" src="../../pics/bgimg2.jpg" id="bgimg" />   

        <div class="md-modal md-effect-1 md-show" id="modal-1">  
            <form action="../../Check" method="POST">  
            <table border="1" class="c-form md-content">  
            <% while(rs.next()){   

            %>  
            <tr>  
                <td><h1><%=rs.getString("question")%>?</h1></td>  
                <td><select name="answer">  
                    <option value="<%=rs.getString("choice1")%>"><%=rs.getString("choice1")%></option>  
                    <option value="<%=rs.getString("choice2")%>"><%=rs.getString("choice2")%></option>  
                    <input type="hidden" name="correct" value="<%=rs.getString("correct")%>"/>  
                </select></td>  
            </tr>  

            <%}  
            %>  

            <tr>  
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Next"/></td>  
            </tr>  

            </table>   

            </form>  
        </div>  



    </body>
```

I'm trying to make an quiz and my query is ORDER BY RAND() so it means it will be random... My JSP send it to servlet to handle the flow but I'm having a problem, I have stored 4 questions with choices (answer) in the database and in my code below I retreive it. Problem is, when I retrieve the answer of the examinee the only retrieved data is the first answer... See my servlet

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>  
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>  
<%@page import="database.Connect" %>  

<%   
    Connect conn = new Connect();   
    Statement stmt = conn.getDataConn().createStatement();  
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from quiz WHERE category = 'secondary' ORDER BY RAND()");  

%>  

<html>  
    <head>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css&js/des.css">  
        <script src="css&js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>  

        <title>Question 1</title>  
    </head>  

    <body>  

        <img alt="" src="../../pics/bgimg2.jpg" id="bgimg" />   

        <div class="md-modal md-effect-1 md-show" id="modal-1">  
            <form action="../../Check" method="POST">  
            <table border="1" class="c-form md-content">  
            <% while(rs.next()){   

            %>  
            <tr>  
                <td><h1><%=rs.getString("question")%>?</h1></td>  
                <td><select name="answer">  
                    <option value="<%=rs.getString("choice1")%>"><%=rs.getString("choice1")%></option>  
                    <option value="<%=rs.getString("choice2")%>"><%=rs.getString("choice2")%></option>  
                    <input type="hidden" name="correct" value="<%=rs.getString("correct")%>"/>  
                </select></td>  
            </tr>  

            <%}  
            %>  

            <tr>  
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Next"/></td>  
            </tr>  

            </table>   

            </form>  
        </div>  



    </body>
```

Servlet... Im just trying to experiment here but I really need help.. The output is null for the for and past code are also fail because the 1st answer is the olnly retrieve and I need to increment it. Please help

```
package Servlet;  

import java.io.IOException;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;  

public class Check extends HttpServlet {  

    @Override  
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {    
            String Answer = request.getParameter("answer" + i);  
            System.out.println(Answer);  
        }   


        String Answer = request.getParameter("answer");  
        String Correct = request.getParameter("correct");  
        int score = 0;  


        if (Answer.equals(Correct)) {  
            score++;  
        }  
        System.out.println(score);  



    }  
}
```

Comment: @Bart :: Sir plz if u may suggest something...

Comment: @Oded ::  Sir plz if u may suggest something.

now this is a Genuine Question i think

Answer (score 0):

It is may be because you select tags has the same name for every question:

```
<select name="answer">
```

I think it should unique